Interest rate to use in black scholes when rates of borrowing and lending are different
I was reading Option pricing and volatility by Sheldon Natenburg and he talks about interest rates and which interest rate to feed to the model. Here is the paragraph from the book(chapter 5):
"The situation is further complicated by the fact that most traders do not borrow and lend at the same rate, so the correct interest rate will, in theory, depend
on whether the trade will create a credit or a debit. In the former case, the trader
will be interested in the borrowing rate; in the latter case, he will be interested in
the lending rate. However, among the inputs into the model—the underlying
price, time to expiration, interest rates, and volatility—interest rates tend to play
the least important role. Using a rate that “makes sense” is usually a reasonable
solution. Of course, for very large positions or for very long-term options, small
changes in the interest rate can have a large impact. But for most traders, getting
the interest rate exactly right is usually not a major consideration."
I am concerned with the statement "In the former case, the trader
will be interested in the borrowing rate; in the latter case, he will be interested in
the lending rate.".
I believe, if I have a credit, I would lend it out to someone, so my rate of interest would be the lending rate and vice versa in the case of debit.
Am I missing something here?
I think, a possible justification of this confusion is that I need to look at the riskless portfolio used in the Black Scholes derivation and looking at the rate we expect it to grow at(by arbitrage arguments)
Is my second interpretation correct or am I misinterpreting the author completely?

The statement in Natenburg's book might be causing confusion due to the specific use of "credit" and "debit" in the context of option trading. Here's a clarification: A credit in option trading doesn't mean someone owes you money. It refers to the net cash inflow you receive when selling an option. This inflow comes with the obligation to potentially buy or sell the underlying asset later. To cover this, you might need to borrow, hence the interest in the borrowing rate. Similarly, a debit isn't a debt you owe. It's the net cash outflow when buying an option. This gives you the right, but not the obligation, to buy or sell the underlying asset. If you have extra cash, you could lend it out, hence the interest in the lending rate.
Your intuition about lending out a credit is valid in a general financial sense, but in option trading, the terms have a different connotation. The focus is on the cash flow's direction due to the trade, not the existence of an actual debt or receivable.
Your second interpretation is on the right track. The Black-Scholes model hinges on the concept of a riskless portfolio. This portfolio should grow at the risk-free rate due to arbitrage arguments. If it doesn't, traders would exploit the opportunity for riskless profit, pushing the option price back to its "fair" value.
Therefore, the relevant interest rate in the model depends on the cash flow from the option trade: If there is a net inflow (credit from selling), the relevant rate is the borrowing rate since you could use this inflow to offset borrowing costs. If there is a net outflow (debit from buying), the relevant rate is the lending rate since you forgo potential interest income by using the cash to buy the option.

When you say net cash inflow or outflow, do you consider the money spent/earned on the underlying to establish the risk less portfolio as well, or is it just the money you get from the option trade only?
